# Javascript Date Object Assignment

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My Javascript assignment this week involves the Date Object. So far i have the following done and it works:

```
var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var weekDaysArray =new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thurs", "Fri");
var reqMonth = prompt("Please enter the number of the month you want to display");
reqMonth = parseInt(reqMonth);

var todaysDate = new Date();
var currYr = todaysDate.getFullYear();
var currMon = todaysDate.getMonth();
var currDate = todaysDate.getDate();
var currDay = todaysDate.getDay();

while((reqMonth == null)||(reqMonth > 12))
{
    reqMonth =  prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 12, corresponding with the month you want to display");
    reqMonth = parseInt(reqMonth);
}

document.write((currMon + 1) + "/" + currDate + "/" + currYr +
"<br />" + "<br />" + monthArray[reqMonth-1] + " " + currYr);
```

This is where things get difficult, at least for me the rest of the assignment is:

5. For each week, use a document.write statement to display this message above the days of the
   week and date: “Week x of month:” where x is a variable used to keep track of the weeks
   processed, starting at 1 and month is the name of the month that is extracted from the
   monthArray using the month number in the variable reqMon.
6. Determine the name of the first day of the requested month.
   a. Using the correct Date Object method, get the integer for the day of the week for the first
   day of the current month.
   (hint 1: you will need to pass the year, month and the day value of 1 to the Date Object
   to get this number
   hint 2:you will use this number to start extracting the names of the day from the array of
   day names, then you will reset it to 0 before starting the next week. )
7. Use a document.write statement to display every day of the current month on a new line in the
   format of the name of the day followed by the integer for the date. See example on page 1.
   a. Use loops to keep track of the number of days written for the month
   b. Use loops to write out the days of the week from the array created in step 2 under the
   name of the requested month and year. (hint: you will need to execute this loop once for
   each week in the month)

The end output hast to be like this:
    11/21/2014 (Current Date) 
    November 2014 (Month selected from prompt)

```
Week 1 of November
Sat 1
Week 2 of November
Sun 2
Mon 3
Tue 4
```

etc….until all days in the month are displayed.

Would I use the Date object I have already instructed to do step 6? Or a whole other one?

Comment: So.. you want us to do your assignment? ;-)

Comment: You have an assignment that requires you to use `document.write()` in 2014? You should tell them to get with the times.

Comment: Do you expect them to teach `document.createElement` and `element.insertBefore` before JavaScript basics?

Comment: No I don't expect you to do my assignment for me, just give me suggestions, pseudo-code, something that could point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Nobody has any suggestions? nobody at all?